# Automating the deletion of donut holes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 and I need a way to automatically delete *parts* of a sketch. For example, I have multiple polygons with numbers inside of them. As shown below, the polygon has the number 28, and under the *edit sketch properties* window, the number 2 is listed under *part 1* and the 8 is listed under *part 2*. I feel like there should be a way to select multiple polygons, and have a script that could delete any vertices that are not included in part 0, that way I would not have to double click each polygon to delete superfluous vertices.

Can this be solved via a tool in ArcGIS?

I want to remove the numbers, not generalize the border.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A Python script can do pretty much *anything*.  Please update the question to contain the script with what you have tried. You should also clarify what you want to accomplish, because it's unclear whether you want help removing the "numbers" or generalizing the border.

Comment: It looks like what you need to do is remove donut holes caused by numbers.  Are there any situations where there is a hole in a polygon not caused by a number?

Comment: @crmackey it is largely numbers, but we used a convert raster to polygon tool, so sometimes there are random marks from the original image we used

Comment: @GISGe Your solution worked wonders, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your features have the same pattern (polygons with numbers as donuts inside), you can explode these multipart features (with [Multipart to Singlepart](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm)) and keep the largest part of the original feature.

An easy way to get rid of the 'numbers' is to [dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) all features from the same original feature based on their initial OBJECTID.